# Fix music player through the navigation

Tags: ajax, seo, navigation, frameset

I'm creating the website of a music band. The band would like to have a music player that remains fixed while you browse the pages, a common problem.

Before you realize I wanted to know which technique is best is:
- Use ajax calls to update the content but keep the player fixed
- Use the system with the frames, so hated?

you would use that technique for a good SEO ranking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Iframe is always a bad SEO practice. To just keep the player fixed you can use CSS (in particular use the `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`). Anyway, as a final suggest, I advice to not start the music when the visitor arrives on your website. It is not a bad SEO practice but it is really annoying.

Comment: thank aurelio, I willn't to start the music from the home page.

If I handle all page with ajax handle can be a solution? This means that every page is loaded in ajax and not as separate links.

Comment: @biancardi If I were you, I would not like to use such system. It can be several problems with crawling if it's not do in the right way (maybe also if it's do well).